# Deploy extra files to the site directory when deploying to Azure Websites from Visual Studio Online

Tags: azure, msbuild, azure-web-app-service, azure-devops

I have been looking at [this article](http://ruslany.net/2014/05/using-azure-web-site-as-a-reverse-proxy/). Part of the article says to place an extra file, `applicationHost.xdt` (the transform for an [Azure Site Extension](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-Site-Extensions)) in the `site` directory. The article mentions placing this file there via ftp.

The `site` directory in an Azure Web Site is the parent of the `wwwroot` directory that is used as the deployment target by the CI build that is configured when you connect an Azure Web Site to Visual Studio Online.

I would like to add the `applicationHost.xdt` file to source control and copy the file to the `site` directory on build. How would I go about modifying the automatically generated visual studio online build to accomplish this?

Comment: Did you ever figure out the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to automatically deploy files to D:\Home\site, the only way to copy files to the D:\Home\site directory upon deployment would be to create a [Custom Deployment Script](http://blog.amitapple.com/post/38417491924/azurewebsitecustomdeploymentpart1/#.VcJkc3nbJaQ)

Alternatively, you could just copy the file there once and not deploy it again since it'll be a relatively static file.